# rp2040 setting gpio interrupt on raise low-high, high-low

Tags: c, embedded, rp2040

I want to setup level change interrupt on a gpio pin(GPIO2) solely through registers to understand innerworkings of the rp2040, but I have failed to do so. From what I understand I need to enable it
in IO_BANK0 PROC0_INTE0, but I don't understand how to actually set a callback function for the interrupt.

I have tried navigating pico-sdk but it is a bit stretchy in a way it's written so I couldn't really make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To enable an interrupt and set its handler function, you could use `irq_set_enabled` and `irq_set_exclusive_handler` from the Pico SDK, as documented here:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/hardware.html#hardware_irq

If you want to write to registers yourself then you should look at the source code of those functions to see how they work.

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: Why?  I pointed you to the documentation of the functions that do what you want.

Comment: Because I literally pointed out that I couldn't make it work by looking at sdk.

Comment: Then provide an [mcve] in your question so we can see what is going wrong.